# Erro de Java Lang Array

Tags: java, array

Boa tarde,estou adaptando este código para fazer a busca baseada em um autômato. O autômato irá procurar datas nos códigos fonte das páginas de internet e irá mostrar no console essas datas. Esta acontecendo um erro de java lang na linha 122 do package buscapadraoweb.

```
package buscapadraoweb;

import buscaweb.CapturaRecursosWeb;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Main {
// busca char em vetor e retorna indice
public static int get_char_ref (char[] vet, char ref ){
    for (int i=0; i<vet.length; i++ ){
        if (vet[i] == ref){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

// busca string em vetor e retorna indice
public static int get_string_ref (String[] vet, String ref ){
    for (int i=0; i<vet.length; i++ ){
        if (vet[i].equals(ref)){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}



//retorna o próximo estado, dado o estado atual e o símbolo lido
public static int proximo_estado(char[] alfabeto, int[][] matriz,int estado_atual,char simbolo){
    int simbol_indice = get_char_ref(alfabeto, simbolo);
    if (simbol_indice != -1){
        return matriz[estado_atual][simbol_indice];
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    //instancia e usa objeto que captura código-fonte de páginas Web
    CapturaRecursosWeb crw = new CapturaRecursosWeb();
    crw.getListaRecursos().add("http://www.mercadolivre.com");
    ArrayList<String> listaCodigos = crw.carregarRecursos();

    String codigoHTML = listaCodigos.get(0);

    //mapa do alfabeto
    char[] alfabeto = new char[11];
    alfabeto[0] = '-';
    alfabeto[1] = '0';
    alfabeto[2] = '1';
    alfabeto[3] = '2';
    alfabeto[4] = '3';
    alfabeto[5] = '4';
    alfabeto[6] = '5';
    alfabeto[7] = '6';
    alfabeto[8] = '7';
    alfabeto[9] = '8';
    alfabeto[10] = '9';



    //mapa de estados
    String[] estados = new String[10];
    estados[0] = "q0";
    estados[1] = "q1";
    estados[2] = "q3";
    estados[3] = "q4";
    estados[4] = "q5";
    estados[5] = "q6";
    estados[6] = "q7";
    estados[7] = "q8";
    estados[8] = "q9";
    estados[9] = "q10";



    String estado_inicial = "q0";

    //estados finais
    String[] estados_finais = new String[1];
    estados_finais[0] = "q10";

    //tabela de transição de AFD para reconhecimento números de dois dígitos
    int[][] matriz = new int[3][11];
    //transições de q0
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q0")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '0')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q1");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q0")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '1')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q1");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q0")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '2')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q1");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q0")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '3')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q1");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q0")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '4')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q1");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q0")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '5')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q1");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q0")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '6')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q1");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q0")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '7')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q1");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q0")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '8')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q1");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q0")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '9')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q1");
    //transições de q1
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q1")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '0')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q2");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q1")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '1')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q2");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q1")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '2')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q2");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q1")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '3')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q2");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q1")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '4')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q2");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q1")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '5')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q2");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q1")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '6')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q2");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q1")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '7')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q2");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q1")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '8')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q2");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q1")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '9')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q2");
    //transições de q2
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q2")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '0')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q3");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q2")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '1')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q3");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q2")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '2')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q3");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q2")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '3')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q3");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q2")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '4')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q3");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q2")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '5')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q3");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q2")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '6')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q3");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q2")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '7')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q3");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q2")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '8')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q3");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q2")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '9')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q3");
    //transições de q3
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q3")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '0')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q4");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q3")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '1')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q4");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q3")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '2')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q4");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q3")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '3')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q4");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q3")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '4')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q4");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q3")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '5')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q4");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q3")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '6')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q4");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q3")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '7')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q4");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q3")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '8')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q4");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q3")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '9')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q4");
    //transições de q4
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q4")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '-')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q5");
    //transições de q5
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q5")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '0')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q6");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q5")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '1')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q6");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q5")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '2')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q6");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q5")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '3')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q6");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q5")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '4')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q6");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q5")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '5')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q6");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q5")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '6')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q6");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q5")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '7')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q6");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q5")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '8')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q6");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q5")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '9')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q6");
    //transições de q6
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q6")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '0')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q7");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q6")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '1')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q7");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q6")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '2')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q7");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q6")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '3')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q7");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q6")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '4')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q7");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q6")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '5')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q7");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q6")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '6')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q7");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q6")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '7')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q7");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q6")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '8')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q7");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q6")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '9')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q7");
    //transições de q7
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q7")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '-')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q8");
    //transições de q8
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q8")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '0')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q9");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q8")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '1')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q9");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q8")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '2')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q9");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q8")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '3')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q9");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q8")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '4')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q9");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q8")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '5')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q9");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q8")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '6')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q9");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q8")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '7')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q9");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q8")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '8')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q9");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q8")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '9')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q9");
    //transições de q9
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q9")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '0')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q10");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q9")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '1')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q10");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q9")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '2')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q10");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q9")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '3')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q10");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q9")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '4')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q10");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q9")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '5')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q10");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q9")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '6')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q10");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q9")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '7')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q10");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q9")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '8')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q10");
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q9")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '9')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q10");
    //transições de q10
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q10")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '0')] = -1;
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q10")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '1')] = -1;
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q10")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '2')] = -1;
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q10")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '3')] = -1;
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q10")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '4')] = -1;
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q10")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '5')] = -1;
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q10")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '6')] = -1;
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q10")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '7')] = -1;
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q10")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '8')] = -1;
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q10")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '9')] = -1;
    matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q10")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '-')] = -1;

    int estado = get_string_ref (estados, estado_inicial);
    int estado_anterior = -1;
    ArrayList<String> palavras_reconhecidas = new ArrayList();

    String palavra = "";

    //varre o código-fonte de um código
    for (int i=0; i<codigoHTML.length(); i++){

        estado_anterior = estado;
        estado = proximo_estado(alfabeto, matriz, estado, codigoHTML.charAt(i));
        //se o não há transição
        if (estado == -1){
            //pega estado inicial
            estado = get_string_ref(estados, estado_inicial);
            // se o estado anterior foi um estado final
            if (get_string_ref(estados_finais, estados[estado_anterior]) != -1){
                //se a palavra não é vazia adiciona palavra reconhecida
                if ( ! palavra.equals("")){
                    palavras_reconhecidas.add(palavra);
                }
                // se ao analisar este caracter não houve transição
                // teste-o novamente, considerando que o estado seja inicial
                i--;
            }
            //zera palavra
            palavra = "";

        }else{
            //se houver transição válida, adiciona caracter a palavra
            palavra += codigoHTML.charAt(i);
        }
    }

    //foreach no Java para exibir todas as palavras reconhecidas
    for (String p: palavras_reconhecidas){
        System.out.println (p);
    }
}
```

}

Abaixo está o erro que acontece:

run:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at buscapadraoweb.Main.main(Main.java:122)
Java Result: 1
```

O código que executa a busca:

```
package buscaweb;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Inet4Address;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SocketHandler;

/**
 *
 * @author Santiago
 */
public class CapturaRecursosWeb {
    private ArrayList<String> listaRecursos = new ArrayList();


    public ArrayList<String> carregarRecursos(){
        ArrayList<String> resultado = new ArrayList();
        for (String stringURL: listaRecursos){
            String resposta = "";

            try {
                URL url = new URL(stringURL);
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                        connection.getInputStream()));

                String inputLine;

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) sb.append(inputLine+"\n");
                resposta = sb.toString();
                resultado.add(resposta);
                in.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return resultado;
    }

    /**
     * @return the listaRecursos
     */
    public ArrayList<String> getListaRecursos() {
        return listaRecursos;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

por que a matriz é de 3x11?

```
int[][] matriz = new int[3][11];
```

se a quantidade de estados é 11 sua matriz deveria ser 11x11

a matriz está acessando um index que não existe
exemplo:

```
matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q6")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '4')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q7");
//get_string_ref(estados, "q6") // index 5
//get_char_ref(alfabeto, '4') // index 5
//get_string_ref(estados, "q7") // index 6
//matriz[5][5] = 6  //erro de index ja que sua matriz é de 3x11
```

> update

faltou o "q2":

```
 String[] estados = new String[10];
    estados[0] = "q0";
    estados[1] = "q1";
    estados[2] = "q2";  <=============
    estados[3] = "q3";
   // ...

  //get_string_ref(estados, "q2"); //index -1
  //matrix[-1][2]//erro de index
```

nao esquece de arrumar os index do estado

no final ficará assim:

```
    String[] estados = new String[11];
    estados[0] = "q0";
    estados[1] = "q1";
    estados[2] = "q2";
    estados[3] = "q3";
    estados[4] = "q4";
    estados[5] = "q5";
    estados[6] = "q6";
    estados[7] = "q7";
    estados[8] = "q8";
    estados[9] = "q9";
    estados[10] = "q10";


    int[][] matriz = new int[11][11];
```

Comment: Agora ele dá o mesmo erro na linha 123...

Comment: Tinha botado dois "q1" nesse novo estado, agora funcionou com essa sua solução...obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

por que a matriz é de 3x11?

```
int[][] matriz = new int[3][11];
```

se a quantidade de estados é 10 sua matriz deveria ser 10x11

a matriz está acessando um index que não existe
exemplo:

```
matriz[get_string_ref(estados, "q6")][get_char_ref(alfabeto, '4')] = get_string_ref(estados, "q7");
//get_string_ref(estados, "q6") // index 5
//get_char_ref(alfabeto, '4') // index 5
//get_string_ref(estados, "q7") // index 6
//matriz[5][5] = 6  //erro de index ja que sua matriz é de 3x11
```

Comment: fiz isso que você falou: int[][] matriz = new int[10][11];

O erro ainda acontece...